# CSS: wrap container element around image and not text even if image is smaller?

Tags: html, css

I would like the red container element to be the width of the image not the text, but it spans to the size of the text because it's wider. How to achieve this?

https://jsfiddle.net/strz3stt/

Note: I'm trying to work with existent markup so I need a way to do this with CSS only as I can't edit the markup.

HTML:

```
<span class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/300">
  <a href="http://google.com">Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google </a>
</span>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: inline-block;
}
.wrapper img {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
.wrapper a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Do you know the size of the image?

Comment: @VladTarniceru no, they are picked by WYSIWYG editors and can be any size. So can't give the wrapper a fixed width unfortunately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming it's your intention to wrap the text of the link to the width of the image, what you can do is turn the wrapper into a table. Then you can force the width to be the width of its contents, by setting `width: 1px`.
(This will also neatly handle the case where a word in the text happens to be wider than the image.)

```css
.wrapper {
  border: 3px solid red;
  display: table; width: 1px;
}
.wrapper img {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 22px);
}
.wrapper a {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<span class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/400/300">
  <a href="http://google.com">Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google Google </a>
</span>
```

Also, you should consider using a `<figure>` rather than a `<span>` for the wrapper. This is precisely what `<figure>` is for.

Comment: Thanks this answers the question but in the real world example the images have a max width of 100% for responsiveness. When that is applied to the example above it doesn't work properly, the image is skewed:

https://jsfiddle.net/strz3stt/2/

Of course this makes perfect sense but any way you can think of having your code work with max width of 100%? I know it can be done easily by editing the markup and adding a few extra elements but as mentioned before I can't change the markup and need to do it through CSS alone.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long, but I only now realised that the solution is to use a max-width in `vw` rather than `%`. See the updated answer. Actually I had to use a `calc`, because 100vw includes the margins of the body; you will have to do some tinkering to make it work the way you need.

Comment: Thanks so much!!  Works great :)